# MEAN stack - structuring app with api, public part and administration?

Tags: api, mean-stack, directory

I'm relatively new to the MEAN stack. I'm writing a web with a public frontend and an administration.

I'm now thinking about structuring the application.

I want to have one api and two websites.

How the folders should be structured?

```
app
  -- admin
  -- api
  -- public
```

Or should I have two different apps with two apis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to do it! Having two apps would be waay to complicated.

Comment: Ok, so the routes should be something like this?

https://kobra.io/#/e/-KEQc2l1AsAoPMVeWmsG

Comment: Yes, and you should also use authorization(I reccomend passport) before sending admin page. Search for passport.js you'll find many good articles, here is one that helped me cereate a good API https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/